# Apply class to every routed component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-components

Is there any way to apply a class to every routed component in Angular. One way is to use `host` property for each component like

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'one',
    host :{class :'my-class'}
    templateUrl: 'one.html',
})
```

but I don't want to write this for every component.

Comment: What do you mean by "routed" component?

Comment: the component that will be rendered on UI based on URL

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you really need to add class or just style all routed components? You can add this to style all routed components:

```
router-outlet + * {
    //your styles
}
```

For angular 6+ use:

```
router-outlet + ::ng-deep * {
    //your styles
}
```

Explanation:

Angular inserts the components next to `<router-outlet>` tag, so the rendered html looks like:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<some-component></some-component>
```

`router-outlet + *` is css selector for any next sibling of `<router-outlet>`

Comment: this is working, but can you explain what does this line mean?

Comment: How could we add a class?

Comment: For angular 6, I needed to add `router-outlet + ::ng-deep * {` otherwise, it would require the * to be same _ngcontent, which the added element isn't. It's its own _nghost.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **`<router-outlet>`**, just a add a div around your outlet and set the class of the div to `"my-class"`.

```
<div class="my-class">        
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: but I want to apply the class to component itself.

Comment: This solution may break if you use 2 layouts. Because "my-class" is rendered in both layouts.

Answer (score 0):

If you use multiple router-outlet in your application, add class to router-outlet, and apply same code as @Ludevik suggested:

```
<div>
  <router-outlet class="routed-module-component"></router-outlet>
  <app-router-component-instance>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- Will not be affected -->
  <app-router-component-instance>
</div>
```

Then reference that class instead of router-outlet:

```
.routed-module-component  + * {
  // add style
}
```